# Laravel 8 - How to save path and redirect to it later when site root is not /?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Is there a way in Laravel to reliably save a path and redirect back to that path later?  The method I have seen does not work when the site root is at /path_to_root/ not / .

Example:  If I save "/path_to_site/mypage?x=y" like this:

```
                $parsedURL = parse_url($request->fullUrl());
                $url = $parsedURL['path'].'?'.$parsedURL['query'];
```

When site root is /path_to_site/, then the `redirect($url);` does not work correctly.   It will redirect to /path_to_site/path_to_site/mypage?x=y

I'm doing this for a login page that's not on the site, so I am not using the Laravel login controller, but even for other purposes, I still want to know how to save a path and redirect to it.  Seems like it should be simple, but I have seen nothing that works.

Comment: this is already tracked and handled by the `Authenticate` middleware which uses `redirect()->guest(...)` method to store the intended URL and `LoginController`s would use `reidrect()->intended(...)` to redirect back to that stored address and fallback to a provided one

Comment: @lagbox I am not using the LoginController.  I am using a custom login that is outside of Laravel, but I will look into this.

Comment: @lagbox is there an example of this anywhere?  The docs don't say much.